# Return a row in a summation query in postgres even if theres no data

Tags: postgresql

I have 3 tables:

- Socktype
- SockStock
- Drawer

..

- Socktype stores a sockId, sockColor and sockLength
- Drawer stores a drawerId and isWood
- Sockstock denotes an amount of a sock type in a specific drawer. it has drawerId,sockId and amount

Now I would like to create a query that gives me all information about a sock and how many socks there are across all the drawers.

I was trying something like this:

```
SELECT 
     coalesce(sum(sockStock.amount),0) as amount,
     sockId,
     sockColor,
     sockLength
FROM SockType
JOIN SockStock ON sockStock.sockId=SockType.sockId
WHERE SockType.sockId=$1
GROUP BY socktype.sockId
```

This does work if theres at least 1 sock in any of the drawers, but if there are no socks of the given type, it does not return a row (which is what I'm trying to prevent with the coalesce.

So is there a way to make this query return the sock information and a zero for amount even if there is no sockstock of the given type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want a LEFT JOIN not a regular JOIN.  It will make it return at least one row for each SockType, with NULLs filled in for columns coming from SockStock where there is no match.

You need the coalesce to convert the NULL to 0, but you need the LEFT for it to have a row in the first place.